# How do I change PDF form field backgrounds when text is entered into them?

Tags: forms, pdf, acrobat, pdf-form

I'm creating a PDF form to distribute to people. When text is not entered into any of the fields on the form, I want it to remain transparent, but when someone enters text into it, I want the background colour of the field to change to white.

[I found this page](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Change-field-background-color-data-entered-q103740.aspx) which describes how you can do it with JavaScript, so I added it to document JavaScripts in my PDF, but it didn't work. The fields continue to have the same transparent background they do by default.

How do I achieve what I'm looking for, with or without JavaScript? I'm using Acrobat Pro DC. Thanks!

Comment: When you distribute the PDF, are you sure that Adobe Reader or Acrobat will be the only tool they use to fill the form? If so, I can put a script in the answer. If you can't control what viewer they will be using, you won't be able to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @joelgeraci I can work around that requirement; I’d love to see that script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this script in the field's custom format script

```
/* Turns off default field highlighting. Normally you'd put this in a doc level script it's just here for completeness */
app.runtimeHighlight = false;
/* The rest of this belongs in the custom format script */
var field = event.target;
if (field.value == field.defaultValue) {
    /* set the fillColor is the field value is the same as the default (generally an empty string) */
    field.fillColor = color.ltGray
}
else {
    field.fillColor = color.transparent
}
```

I have a functioning [example file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jabunk9twn21czv/highlightWhenEmpty.pdf?dl=1).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make an example file!